# Internal purchases in the android application

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

The application already includes purchases of internal currency through google pay, but I can buy a certain amount of currency only 1 time, the next time the payment dialog does not start. Why is this happening ? maybe I need to configure something in the play console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have to consume your purchase, as such:

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(result: BillingResult, purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
    purchases?.forEach { consumePurchase(it) }
}

private fun consumePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
    val consumeParams = ConsumeParams
        .newBuilder()
        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
        .build()

    billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams) { result, _ ->
        if (result.responseCode == OK) {

        }
    }
}
```

This signals to the Play Store that your app has received the update and processed it in it's backend, so it's ready for a second purchase. You can still do this by calling `billingClient.queryPurchaseHistory(INAPP)`.